# User languages settings - most efficient way to get setting and display it

Tags: php, mysql, performance, localization, server

I am building a site or multiple languages for logged in users. if I have a table named `user_settings` and a column called `language`, I can save the language, for example `en` for english and `es` for spanish.

i can also store it using a cookie (i think). which would be the most efficient way?

i think the database way is the best way but the only way to show the message for each page is to execute a query saying, `SELECT language from user_settings` and then do an `if statement`.

```
if($languageFromDatabase == 'en')
```

but i dont think that is effient because i would have to check the database on every page load. what would be an effient way?

Answer (score 3):

Read the language from the database on the first visit of the user. Store it into the session data and read from there afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Store language in the cookie.
And then if there is get parameter $_GET['lng'] only then execute the sql and store it in the cookie again.

That way the sql will be executed only when the user wants to change the language.

Answer (score 0):

You need the cookie to keep track of the user.

My comments, roughly in order from best to worst:

Plan A:  It could either keep *only* the user_id.  This necessitates a fetch from the database for various user info at the start of each page.

Plan B:  Keep all info in the cookie.  This runs the risk of having a bulky cookie, hacking of the cookie, etc.  And it may lead to transition problems when you add something else you need to keep for each user.

Plan C:  Pass in URLs.  This is terribly prone to hacking and is clumsy when someone wants to bookmark or share a URL.

Plan D:  Session storage is bad if you ever expect to grow to the point where you need multiple web servers.  (The heavy hitters have no use for "session".)